# my snake go backwards when the horizontal and vertical

Tags: python, pygame

i'm making a game but when i hit the horizontal and vertical keys at the same time or pressed fast enough, my snake go backwards, which will make a game over screen happen if it's longer then 2 blocks.

I tried making a long if statement. And cleaned up the code.

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, 16, 2, 262144)
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*
import cv2
import time
import random
import pickle
import shutil

dw = 1280
dh = 720 
at = 40
bs = 20
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((dw, dh))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def pause():

    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    menu(1)
        screen.fill(white)
        mts("Paused", black, -100, 100)
        mts("Press esc to go back to the game or press space to go back to the menu", black, 25, 45)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

#define the apple to spawn in a random place
def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, dw-at, bs)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, dh-at, bs)

    return randAppleX,randAppleY

def snake(bs, sl):
    for XnY in sl:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Dgreen, [XnY[0],XnY[1],bs,bs])

def gameLoop():
    global at
    global bs
    hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    gameHack = False
    Speed = 20
    lead_x = dw/2
    lead_y = dh/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 'music1.ogg'))
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 

    slist = []
    sl = 0
    if sl > 2304:
        gameHack = True

    randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Game over", red, -50,100)
            mts("Press enter to play again or press space to go back to the menu", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        gameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        gameExit = False
                        gameOver = False
                        menu(1)
        while gameHack == True:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Hacked", red, -50,100)
            mts("You hacked or exploit the game, press enter to quit the game", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and lead_x_change != bs:
                    lead_x_change = -bs
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and lead_x_change != -bs:
                    lead_x_change = bs
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and lead_y_change != bs:
                    lead_y_change = -bs
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and lead_y_change != -bs:
                    lead_y_change = bs
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s and Speed >= 10 and Speed < 60:
                    Speed += 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and Speed <= 60 and Speed > 10:
                    Speed -= 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)

        if not pygame.Rect(0, 0, dw, dh).contains(lead_x, lead_y, bs, bs):
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        screen.fill(white)

        #draw the apple
        apple = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [randAppleX,randAppleY,at,at])

        sh = []
        sh.append(lead_x)
        sh.append(lead_y)
        slist.append(sh)
        snake(bs, slist)

        if len(slist) > sl:
            del slist[0]

        for eachSegment in slist[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == sh:
                gameOver = True

        score(sl)
        highscore(hs)

        if sl > hs:
            hs += 1
            os.remove( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN') )
            pickle.dump( sl, open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "wb" ) )
            hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )


        pygame.display.update()

        #make the apple spawn
        if lead_x > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleX + at or lead_x + bs > randAppleX and lead_x + bs < randAppleX + at:
            if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + at:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                sl += 1
            elif lead_y + bs > randAppleY and lead_y + bs < randAppleY + at:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                sl += 1


        clock.tick(Speed)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

I expected it to not go backwards, even though there's a code for it. I still go backwards. How do you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs, because the events are handled in a loop:

> ```
> for event in pygame.event.get():
>
>    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
>
>        # [...]
> ```

Lets assume the snake moves to the left and `lead_x_change == -bs` respectively `lead_y_change == 0`. If (e.g.) `pygame.K_UP` is pressed and the following condition is fulfilled:

> ```
> elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and lead_y_change != bs:
> ```

This causes that the movement state changes to `lead_x_change = 0` and `lead_y_change = -bs`.

If the `pygame.K_RIGHT` was pressed a bit later, but fast enough to be handled in the same frame of the main loop, then it is handled in the event loop, one pass later. This causes that the following condition is fulfilled, too:

> ```
> elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and lead_x_change != -bs:
> ```

Now the movement state changes to `lead_x_change = bs` and `lead_y_change = 0`. It seems, that the snake turned by 180 degrees. Indeed it change the direction from left to upward and from upwards to right in one frame (in one pass of the main loop, but 2 passes of the event loop).

Fortunately the issue can be solved with ease. Just copy the values of `lead_x_change` and `lead_y_change` before the event loop and use the copies to evaluate the movement conditions in the event loop.
Note the conditions have to check against the state of `lead_x_change` and `lead_y_change`, which they had have at the begin of the frame:

```py
prev_x, prev_y = lead_x_change, lead_y_change 
for event in pygame.event.get():

    # [...]

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and prev_x != bs:
            lead_x_change, lead_y_change = -bs, 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and prev_x != -bs:
            lead_x_change, lead_y_change = bs, 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and prev_y != bs:
            lead_x_change, lead_y_change = 0, -bs
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and prev_y != -bs:
            lead_x_change, lead_y_change = 0, bs

        # [...]
```

Comment: @Desjul20 No, it never will go backwards. It's always tested against `prev_x`, `prev_y`

Comment: Okay, realized the mistake i did when copying your code and it fixed it. Sorry for that.